# How to print or store a selected column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have write down a code to select a column from a complex csv file having 10 columns and 1473 rows when i select a column and print it down with the given code outcome is like given bellow, it print only certain lines 14 from top and 14 from bottom. how can i print all the rows with the given code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('460.csv')
saved_column = df['Outcome'] 
print saved_column



>>>

0          Active
1          Active
2          Active
3          Active
4     Unspecified
5     Unspecified
6     Unspecified
7     Unspecified
8     Unspecified
9     Unspecified
10    Unspecified
11    Unspecified
12    Unspecified
13    Unspecified
14    Unspecified
...
1459    Inconclusive
1460    Inconclusive
1461    Inconclusive
1462    Inconclusive
1463    Inconclusive
1464    Inconclusive
1465    Inconclusive
1466    Inconclusive
1467    Inconclusive
1468    Inconclusive
1469    Inconclusive
1470    Inconclusive
1471    Inconclusive
1472    Inconclusive
1473             NaN
Name: Outcome, Length: 1474, dtype: object
```

thanks and regards

Comment: Set `pd.options.display.max_rows` (default 60) to a larger value or to None (unlimited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the default print options you can either change them:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows',None)
```

or convert to a string

```
print(df.to_string())
```